# Unable to Scroll till listview till view in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            android:title="SofAgeTinder"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"

                android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cartbutton"

                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
            android:text="CheckOut"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/order_review_content_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:divider="@color/lightGrey"
                android:dividerHeight="1.0dip"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:overScrollFooter="@android:color/transparent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/orderReview_priceBox"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/order_review_price_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.0dip"
                    android:background="@color/orderReview_orderBtn"
                    android:layerType="software" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
                    android:paddingTop="10.0dip">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
                        android:paddingTop="3.0dip">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:text="Total"
                            android:textColor="@color/orderReview_priceHeading"
                            android:textSize="15.0sp" />

                        <RelativeLayout

                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:gravity="end">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/totaltextview"

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="15.0sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
                        android:paddingTop="3.0dip">

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:text="Shipping"
                            android:textColor="@color/orderReview_priceHeading"
                            android:textSize="15.0sp" />

                        <RelativeLayout

                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:gravity="end">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/cart_body_shipping"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="15.0sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/pepper_cash_row"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
                        android:paddingTop="3.0dip">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2.0"

                            android:textColor="@color/orderReview_priceHeading"
                            android:textSize="15.0sp" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:gravity="end">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/minus_sign"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="-"
                                android:textColor="@color/previousOrder_orderId_title"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/review_pepper_cash"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minus_sign"

                                android:textSize="15.0sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip"
                    android:background="#ffc0c0c0"
                    android:layerType="software" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10.0dip">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="Payble"
                        android:textColor="@color/product_title"
                        android:textSize="20.0sp" />

                    <RelativeLayout

                        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:gravity="end">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cart_body_total"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="20.0sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/checkout"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/brand_green_btn"
                    android:text="CONTINUE CHECKOUT"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

i have given Xml and am Printing data in listview i am Problem facing in scrolling listitem till green color view if we have many item then it scroll but always last two item not scrolling till Green color view please suggest me how to scroll listview item till green color view  in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your ListView

```
android:layout_above="@+id/orderReview_priceBox"
```

like this

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/orderReview_priceBox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@color/lightGrey"
            android:dividerHeight="1.0dip"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:overScrollFooter="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: using this transparent becomes gone

Comment: you want listview till end and want scrool full?

Comment: see in given solution is good but in  jo total shiping payble part sab apne ko trnaspernt chaiye so that user can see that there is below item

Comment: There is no way for that, but you can do one thing. Add 2-3 empty items at the end of listView. It might work

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView is getting hide behind linearlayout "orderReview_priceBox". Please arrange proper layout as per your requirement.